# snmpget returns value encoded in 5 bytes

Tags: linux, openwrt, net-snmp

When I do an snmpget, the value of the RSSI signal returned by my MIB is encoded in 5 bytes.
It's an Integer but prefixed with 00 .
why?
Openwrt net-snmp-5.8

```
trace: snmp_pdu_parse(): snmp_api.c, 4461
dumph_recv:     error status
dumpx_recv:      02 01 00 
dumpv_recv:        Integer:     0 (0x00)
trace: snmp_pdu_parse(): snmp_api.c, 4472:
dumph_recv:     error index
dumpx_recv:      02 01 00 
dumpv_recv:        Integer:     0 (0x00)
trace: snmp_pdu_parse(): snmp_api.c, 4490:
dumph_recv:     VarBindList
trace: snmp_pdu_parse(): snmp_api.c, 4506:
dumph_recv:       VarBind
trace: snmp_parse_var_op(): snmp.c, 164:
dumph_recv:         Name
dumpx_recv:          06 0D 2B 06 01 04 01 81 DB 41 07 0C 01 15 01 
dumpv_recv:            ObjID: iso.3.6.1.4.1.28097.7.12.1.21.1
trace: snmp_pdu_parse(): snmp_api.c, 4515:
dumph_recv:         Value
dumpx_recv:          02 05 00 FF FF FC 19 
dumpv_recv:          truncating signed value **4294966297** to 32 bits (1)
  Integer:      4294966297 (0xFFFFFC19)
trace: _sess_process_packet(): snmp_api.c, 5249:
sess_process_packet: received message id#0 reqid#1927527062 len 53
trace: snmp_synch_input(): snmp_client.c, 183:
snmp_synch: Response (ReqID: 1927527062 - Cmd 162)
trace: sprint_realloc_by_type(): mib.c, 1999:
output: sprint_by_type, type 2
iso.3.6.1.4.1.28097.7.12.1.21.1 = INTEGER: 4294966297
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a BER encoding thing thing - you can't have a sequence of 9 or more high-bits or low bits at the start of the number, you can see this in the [code encoding an int](https://github.com/net-snmp/net-snmp/blob/fb4b53def8575125c25092e9b0d8d6311c3b8571/snmplib/asn1.c#L739), or [the spec](https://www.itu.int/ITU-T/studygroups/com17/languages/X.690-0207.pdf).

When the number is small, but non-negative, you'll see a prefix of `0xff` at the start, as the leading bits of the number will be `0b000000000`, which is not permitted, so it inserts a `0b11111111` to make the value valid.
When the number is a small, negative number, you'll see a prefix of `0x00` at the start, as the leading bits of the number will be `0b111111111`, which is not permitted, so it inserts a `0b00000000` to make the value valid.

From [`ISO/IEC 8825-1:2003`](https://www.itu.int/ITU-T/studygroups/com17/languages/X.690-0207.pdf) - section 8.3.2

> If the contents octets of an integer value encoding consist of more than one octet, then the bits of the first octet
> and bit 8 of the second octet:
> a) shall not all be ones; and
> b) shall not all be zero.

Comment: Mind you, it sort of reads like an encoding error, as you could have encoded this negative number properly in 2 bytes if you were following DER encoding rules

Comment: When I changed the sign of the returned value to (-4294966297) in my MIB sources. the result is correct, the default RSSI value returned -999 displayed in decimal is coded in 2 Bytes.
the asn_build_int() function is no longer called, the called function is just asn_parse_int() . 
Why this value (-4294966297) coded in 64 bits returned a correct number to me knowing that even this one does not respect the ASN.1 standard for BER coding. Ps:my long is 8  bytes  and int 4 Bytes